# centrally symmetric and centered about the origin regarding ellipsoids

Tags: convex-optimization, symmetry, centroid

I need your help in understanding why the following statement is true:

"Since $\mathit{A}^\prime$ is centrally symmetric, $MVEE(\mathit{A}^\prime)$
is centered at the origin", which is quoted from [On Khachiyan’s Algorithm for the Computation of
Minimum Volume Enclosing Ellipsoids](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/miketodd/TYKhach.pdf)

Is there a proof for such statement, since i have not found any reference in the paper regarding this issue??

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: Central symmetry means that if $x\in A$, then $-x\in A$ as well. Is it not intuitive that this must be true for the MVEE as well?

Comment: it is but why is it centered about the origin ?

Comment: Every point $x\in A$ has a corresponding point $-x\in A$. The midpoint between those two points is always the origin. Again, that's just the intuition, not an answer, but still...

Comment: Do you know of a mathematical proof for this issue??

Comment: If I did I'd be posting an answer. :-)